# Is there a way to use a Doctrine reserved word in a DQL statement?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

Is there a way to use a Doctrine reserved word in a DQL statement?

I would like to use an Entity class called "**Member**" but I cannot use it neither with QueryBuilder nor Query, aliases, etc.

Examples :

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m.id')
  ->from('Member', 'm')
  ->where('m.id=1234');
return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

or

```
$q = $entityManager->createQuery('select m.id from Member m');
return $q->getArrayResult();
```

both examples give the following error:

**Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_ALIASED_NAME, got 'Member'**

**Note :** the table name is not the problem since it's not Member

Comment: Just for kicks, in your first example try using `from(Member::class,`

Comment: Already tried. Same error unfortunately.

Comment: Seems I am not the only one to use this reserved word... 
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7264

Comment: I made a quick test by creating a Member entity.  Did not even bother to change the table name since `member` was only a reserved word in mysql for a couple of point versions.  I ran your code exactly and besides getting the lexer error I got `SELECT m.id FROM Member m WHERE m.id=1234`.  Notice the capital M in the Member table name.  So I used `from(Member::class,` as suggested in my first comment (note no quotes around Member::class) and it all worked.  Unless your entities really have no namespace at all then using just 'Member' is not going to work.

Comment: The issue you linked is interesting.  I suspect it was also a namespace problem but you would think some of the people participating would have pointed that out.  I ran my test inside of the Symfony framework with an `App\Entity\Member` entity.  Your tags indicate you might be using Doctrine standalone?  If `Member` really is your fully qualified class name then perhaps you could update your question with your [bootstrap configuration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager) and I'll test standalone.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I am indeed using Doctrine with CodeIgniter 4 (it’s a bit like a standalone then). 

It works if I use ‘\Member’ instead of ‘Member’. The problem was thus the namespace. 

Thank you!

Comment: Good to know but there is still something strange about the specific name `Member`.  I made a standalone orm app following the getting started guide.  The example `Product` entity worked as expected without any namespace or backslash.  But `Member` did not without adding the backslash.  `Memberx` worked fine.  I did not search any further.  Might be wise to just use a different entity name.  Might avoid future issues.

Comment: It seems Member is a reserved word in DQL. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf